# (sfm) How can I resize bones in 3 axises of models when editing .smd files in blender

Tags: bones

I've tried to resize limbs on some models from sfm but so far i could only resize whole model. i can easily do what i want in pose mode but when i export it into .smd, there are no changes. in editing mode this seem to be complicated as i need to work with meshes and bones positions. barely started using blender and i dont want to go deep, only wanted to resize some bones. sfm offers scaling but only in x,y,z at same time.

Comment: edit isn't too complicated. you should try it.

Comment: i tried and end up with broken meshes with gaps and some othe weird things that i dont know how to fix.

Comment: Editing the armature will not affect the mesh in any way.

Comment: so what should i do to for example resize legs in z axis. cause in this point i dont know.

Comment: select the bones. scale on the z axis. [s]+[z]

Comment: did that many times. scaled thigh and calf bone in z axis. bone point becomes line. when i export and view model leg is bend in weird shape and looks wrong. if i scale in pose mode its all good but i dont know any way to export it and keeping changes.

Comment: hmmmm. may you upload a .blend file? sounds like a weight error. Use [pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/)

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34034   When i use pose mode i can easily make leg shorter by scaling down z on thigh bone. when i export, no changes. when scale thigh bone in edit mode, nothing changes. when i scale all bones in leg in z, then i get some cliped mess and wrong shapes.

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to do? make it a midget?

Comment: not having certain objective yet. generaly, y, want to shorten some limbs for now. i want to be able to scale any part of body on any model in x,y,z. i use models in sfm. i can scale each bone in sfm but in only x,y,z simultaneously. so now i look for some way to scale on separate axis. blender looks like hard way. gona try 3ds later, maybe its easier there. used xsi and it took me 2min, but then i cant recompile model into .mdl due to some errors. outdated addons. only thing i can do in blender without ppblems so far is scale whole model.